# kafka connect-standalone.properties, connect-file-source.properties error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

hello I have problem about kafka standalone

I want to execute kafka using connect-file-source.properties and connect-standalone.properties.

connect-file-source.properties

```
name=local-file-source
connector.class=FileStreamSource
tasks.max=1
file=/home/wootag/test.txt
topic=connect-test
```

connect-standalone.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
```

If I enter these commands

```
$ bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties
```

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/kafka/bin/../logs/server.log (Permission denied)
```

error occurred when it was executed.

So I  go to kafka-run-class.sh.
`export LOG_DIR=/var/log/kafka/`
Enter these commands.

```
chmod 777 kafka
```

and retry these commands

```
$ bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties
```

```
$ bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties cd
[2023-03-20 18:36:45,067] INFO Kafka Connect standalone worker initializing ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:68)
[2023-03-20 18:36:45,076] INFO WorkerInfo values:
   jvm.args = -Xms256M, -Xmx2G, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35, -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent, -XX:MaxInlineLevel=15, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false, -Dkafka.logs.dir=/var/log/kafka/, -Dlog4j.configuration=file:bin/../config/connect-log4j.properties
   jvm.spec = Ubuntu, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 11.0.18, 11.0.18+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04
   jvm.classpath = /home/wootag/kafka/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/home/wootag/kafka/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar:/home/wootag/kafka/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/home/wootag/kafka/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/home/wootag/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/home/wootag/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/home/wootag/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-api-3.4.0.jar:/home/wootag/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-3.4.0.jar:/home/wootag/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-json-3.4.0.jar:/home/wootag/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-3.4.0.jar:/home/wootag/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-client-2.13.4.jar:/home/wootag/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-

[2023-03-20 18:36:49,437] ERROR Failed to create job for config/connect-file-source.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:111)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,438] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:121)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches FileStreamSource, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:115)
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:99)
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:118)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches FileStreamSource, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.connectorClass(Plugins.java:249)
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.newConnector(Plugins.java:220)
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$getConnector$6(AbstractHerder.java:689)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.getConnector(AbstractHerder.java:689)
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:457)
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$2(AbstractHerder.java:377)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,442] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:66)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,442] INFO Stopping REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:317)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,478] INFO Stopped http_8083@51b01960{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8083} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector:383)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,478] INFO node0 Stopped scavenging (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:149)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,485] INFO REST server stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:334)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,485] INFO Herder stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:106)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,486] INFO Worker stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:219)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,488] INFO Stopped FileOffsetBackingStore (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore:66)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,488] INFO Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:693)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,489] INFO Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:697)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,489] INFO Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:703)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,489] INFO App info kafka.connect for 127.0.1.1:8083 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:83)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,489] INFO Worker stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:240)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,491] INFO Herder stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:124)
[2023-03-20 18:36:49,491] INFO Kafka Connect stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:71)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding log directory, you don't need to put Kafka under `/usr/local`. But, changing `LOG_DIR` is one correct solution for that error, though, typically best done in SystemD script.

> Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches FileStreamSource

`FileStreamSource` connector was removed from the default `plugin.path` because it is not recommended to be used outside of demo purposes.

You would have to manually add it back by adding its filepath in the `connect-standalone.properties` file